# Find all points along a path AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bezier

Basically, I want to randomly add a movie clip to any point along a bezier curve. Is there a way to find all points along a path? Or maybe there's a way to find the equation (it's a quadratic curve)? If all else fails, is there a way to find the points along a straight line (that isn't perfectly horizontal or vertical)?

Comment: How is the line or curve being created? Is it a vector, is it bitmap?

Comment: Honestly, if it's possible one way, I'll switch to that. Right now I just drew some paths with the pen tool.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: Some answers that may be helpful also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935117/how-can-i-convert-curveto-to-a-list-of-points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the pen tool, this is creating a `Shape`. You can access the path of this shape by reading the result from `Shape.graphics.readGraphicsData()`

See the reference for [readGraphicsData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData%28%29).

Comment: +1 this pretty handy, easier than manually computing x,y for traversal(0.0 to 1.0) on the bezier curve